# Inconsistent looping behaviours of For loop in vba

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I've written a macro for deleting MS Word 2010 pages as follows-

```
Sub deleteAlternatePages()
    CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    TotalPages = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)

    maxLoop = TotalPages - 1

    Dim loopCtr As Integer
    loopCtr = (maxLoop / 2)

    For i = 1 To loopCtr
        boolDelete = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        Call deleteOnePage
        CurPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1
    Next

End Sub
```

The loop doesn't work properly when I run the macro from word. But, works properly when I debug the code.

Comment: When you say the loop doesn't work properly, what exactly happens that shouldn't be happening?

Comment: The loop doesn't complete till the max value of counter and some of the pages left as it is in last.

Answer (score 6):

This is just a hunch, but I bet you are deleting pages you don't intend to? Instead of looping UP, loop backwards

```
 For i =loopCtr to 1 step -1
```

In your loop, if you deleted a page, the rest of the pages get moved up a page and will have incorrect page numbers as you continue to check them forward. If you delete from the end first, the pages at the front won't be messed with

Comment: +1 You must always loop backwards or use object names when deleting from a collection in VBA, because the collection is changing as you delete.